# Difference between the limit and partial sums of Leibniz formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

Lebniz's formula shows that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} \frac{1}{2n+1}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Playing with partial sums, I have checked "by hand" that it seems that $$\frac{\pi}{4}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n} \frac{1}{2n+1}=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{4(n+1)}+O\left((-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{2(2n+1)^{3}}\right)$$

Is it right? Is there any way to prove it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes (both questions).

Comment: Thanks @ProfessorVector, could you share how could it be showed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct, though the notation is a bit on the... erm... heterodox side, so let's figure it out: the big O is about order of magnitude, $$f(n)=O(g(n))$$ just means
$$|f(n)|\le C|g(n)|$$ for $n>n_0.$ Meaning your claim would be equivalent to $$\frac{\pi}{4}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k} \frac{1}{2k+1}=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{4(n+1)}+O\left(n^{-3}\right),$$ while in reality, you (probably) want to say quite a bit more, $$\frac{\pi}{4}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k} \frac{1}{2k+1}=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{4(n+1)}+r_n,$$
where $$r_n\sim(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{2(2n+1)^{3}}.$$
Of course, $$\frac{\pi}{4}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k} \frac{1}{2k+1}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k} \frac{1}{2k+1}$$
Now there's the famous method of telescoping: if $a_k=b_k-b_{k+1}$, then we have $$\sum^n_{k=0}a_k=b_0-b_{n+1},\quad\sum^\infty_{k=n+1}a_k=b_{n+1}-\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n.$$

In the case at hand, we have $$\frac1{4k}+\frac1{4(k+1)}=\frac{2k+1}{4k(k+1)}=\frac1{2k+1}+\frac1{4k(k+1)(2k+1)}$$and after multiplication by $(-1)^k$
$$\frac{(-1)^k}{4k}-\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{4(k+1)}=\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}+\frac{(-1)^k}{4k(k+1)(2k+1)}.$$ This implies
$$\sum^\infty_{k=n+1}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{4(n+1)}-\sum^\infty_{k=n+1}\frac{(-1)^k}{4k(k+1)(2k+1)},$$ and since the sum on the RHS is alternating and with decreasing summands, it's not bigger than the first term, and since $4n(n+1)=(2n+1)^2-1,$ that has the right asymptotics. Your proposed error term is one half of that, and that's typical for such a series with a polynomial in the denominator, but you need another technique (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersSeriesTransformation.html).

Comment: Thanks @ProfessorVector, really useful answer!